# Running gulp-tslint results in unhandled stream error in pipe

Tags: visual-studio-2015, gulp, tslint

Hi I am tring to integrate gulp-tslint into my application. I am using visual studio 2015 so the tooling for generating js from typescript is in place.

Here is my package.json file:

```
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "Project",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.18",
    "es6-promise": "3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "0.34.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10",
    "d3": "3.5.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-tslint": "4.3.3"
  }
}
```

Here is my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var tslint = require('gulp-tslint');

gulp.task('lint', function () {
    return gulp.src("./app/**/*.ts")
        .pipe(tslint())
        .pipe(tslint.report("verbose"));
});
```

This is the error I am getting when trying to run the build task from task runner explorer:

[image]

All my typescript code is in the root app folder with multiple subfolders.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like an error with parsing a .json file, possibly your tslint.json file. I'd check to make sure it doesn't have any syntax errors.

Comment: I get the same error. I checked my tslint.json with http://jsonlint.com/ and it's a valid JSON